# Is there a way to mass-rename an object's suffix?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I like to bake my models in Substance Painter. It bakes by mesh name so I don't have to explode the mesh. I have to end the name of each object with _low or _high.

renaming 30 or 40 objects gets tedious. Is there a way to grab everything that is .00# and change it to _high?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not natively, no, but you can try one of these addons:

1. Name Panel Addon http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?272086-Addon-Item-Panel-amp-Batch-Naming-1-4 or
2. Batch Rename Datablocks http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Object/Batch_Rename_Datablocks

Comment: The first one is great, that's just what I needed. Thanks Duarte :)

Comment: I use it myself frequently and works really well